# Mysqli Join unexpected ";"

Tags: mysql

im getting an error for unexpected ";" on this code. Dont know where the issue is :(

```
$getProducts = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
               orders.id AS id,
               orders_items.qty AS qty,
               shopping_products.title AS title
               FROM orders 
               JOIN orders_items ON orders_items.ordersID = orders.id
               JOIN shopping_products ON shopping_products.id = orders_items.shopping_productsID
               WHERE orders.authorID = ".$userID.""
);
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to injection, which may in fact be the cause here. What's `$userID` in this case?

Comment: This code should not generate any parse errors. Verify that this  is actually the problem line - often when seeing errors like _unexpected <token>_, the actual problem is on the line before the one reported.

Comment: $userID         = (int) $_POST["userID"];

prior to this cant be any errors, thats why its weird... If i take this block out all works fine...